# Laravel Eloquent retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have four tables

```
**Articles table**

 id
 title
 body
 owner_id
 category_id

**Favorite articles table**

  id
  user_id
  article_id

**User table**

 id
 user_name
 user_type

**Category table**

 id
 category_name
```

How to get list of favorite articles (article_name,owner_name,category_name) which related to currently logged user  from db using laravel eloquent?

Is it possible to do it in single line request? e.g.:

```
$articles_data=Auth::user()->favorite_articles->article...
```

**EDIT**
For the moment i have to use statement below:

```
$articles_data = FavoriteArticle::where('user_id', Auth::id())->join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'favorite_articles.article.id')
                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'favorite_articles.user_id')
                            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.id')
                            ->get()
```

Which looks a bit complicated and doesn't use eloquent relations.

Comment: You can simply setup a [many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between the `User` model and the `Article` model.

Comment: Yes I can, but how to get data from other tables (category_name value)

Comment: @user947668 i updated my answer, hope it helps. cheers

Comment: unfortunately question is still not answered. As @Bogdan suggested i created many to many relationship but this relation doesn't not allow me to retrive category_name value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completing @zippo_ answer, in the `Controller` you must reference what tables you want, e.g.

*User.php*

```
use Article;

public function article()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Article');
}
```

and in the e.g. *UserController.php*

```
$user = User::with('article')->get();
```

EDIT:

if you want to relate User to Article.Category, after create a relation with user and article

*Article.php*

```
use Category;

public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Category');
}
```

e.g. *UserController.php*

```
$user_articles_categories = User::with('article.category')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of laravel eager loading, which are also called as Eloquent relationships.

Eloquent relationships are defined as functions on your Eloquent model classes.

Eg. In Article Model

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Category');
}
```

In this way, you need to define all the relationships in the respective Model classes.

for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships